# Get variable from json select option php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON decoded array in php with foreach that includes a select option in a form every time I select an option from this drop down it returns the last value in the list. I'm trying to save the flatnumber,building,address1 variables. How do I go about this?

```
    $api_url = 'http://rest.api?postcode=' . urlencode($_GET['postcode']);
    $api_json = file_get_contents($api_url);
    $api_array = json_decode($api_json, true);
    $address = $api_array['addresses'];
    foreach($address as $addresses){
    echo '<option>'.$addresses['address'].'</option>';
        $flatnumber = $addresses['flatNumber'];
        $address1 = $addresses['building'];
        $address2 = $addresses['address1'];
        $town = $addresses['town'];
        $county = $addresses['county'];
    }
```

Here's the array:

```
    Array ( [links] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [queries] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => searchByPostcode [parameters] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => GL50 2Tj [name] => postcode [validateAs] => /validate/ukPostcode ) ) ) ) [rel] => /rels/domestic/address-lookup /rels/self [uri] => http://?b=2jmj7l5rSw0yVb_vlWAYkK_YBwk{&postcode} ) [1] => Array ( [rel] => /rels/home [uri] => http:// ) ) [addresses] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [address] => 22, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [address1] => Andover Road [building] => 22 [county] => Gloucestershire [deliveryPointSuffix] => 1A [dependentLocality] => [dependentThorofare] => [doubleDependentLocality] => [flatNumber] => [houseName] => [houseNumber] => 22 [id] => |22||Andover Road||CHELTENHAM|Gloucestershire|GL50 2TJ|22|||1Al|ElecM|NoGasM|NoIGT| [igtWarning] => Unknown [knownElectricityMeter] => 1 [knownGasMeter] => [name] => 22, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [postCode] => GL50 2TJ [town] => CHELTENHAM ) [1] => Array ( [address] => 24, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [address1] => Andover Road [building] => 24 [county] => Gloucestershire [deliveryPointSuffix] => 1L [dependentLocality] => [dependentThorofare] => [doubleDependentLocality] => [flatNumber] => [houseName] => [houseNumber] => 24 [id] => |24||Andover Road||CHELTENHAM|Gloucestershire|GL50 2TJ|24|||1Lw|ElecM|GasM|NoIGT| [igtWarning] => NoIGT [knownElectricityMeter] => 1 [knownGasMeter] => 1 [name] => 24, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [postCode] => GL50 2TJ [town] => CHELTENHAM ) [2] => Array ( [address] => Flat Above, 24-26, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [address1] => Andover Road [building] => 24-26 [county] => Gloucestershire [deliveryPointSuffix] => [dependentLocality] => [dependentThorofare] => [doubleDependentLocality] => [flatNumber] => Flat Above [houseName] => [houseNumber] => 24-26 [id] => Flat Above|24-26||Andover Road||CHELTENHAM|Gloucestershire|GL50 2TJ|24-26||||ElecM|NoGasM|NoIGT| [igtWarning] => Unknown [knownElectricityMeter] => 1 [knownGasMeter] => [name] => Flat Above, 24-26, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [postCode] => GL50 2TJ [town] => CHELTENHAM ) [3] => Array ( [address] => 24-26, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [address1] => Andover Road [building] => 24-26 [county] => Gloucestershire [deliveryPointSuffix] => 1B [dependentLocality] => [dependentThorofare] => [doubleDependentLocality] => [flatNumber] => [houseName] => [houseNumber] => 24-26 [id] => |24-26||Andover Road||CHELTENHAM|Gloucestershire|GL50 2TJ|24-26|||1Bm|ElecM|NoGasM|NoIGT| [igtWarning] => Unknown [knownElectricityMeter] => 1 [knownGasMeter] => [name] => 24-26, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [postCode] => GL50 2TJ [town] => CHELTENHAM ) [4] => Array ( [address] => 26, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [address1] => Andover Road [building] => 26 [county] => Gloucestershire [deliveryPointSuffix] => 1N [dependentLocality] => [dependentThorofare] => [doubleDependentLocality] => [flatNumber] => [houseName] => [houseNumber] => 26 [id] => |26||Andover Road||CHELTENHAM|Gloucestershire|GL50 2TJ|26|||1Ny|NoElecM|GasM|NoIGT| [igtWarning] => NoIGT [knownElectricityMeter] => [knownGasMeter] => 1 [name] => 26, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [postCode] => GL50 2TJ [town] => CHELTENHAM ) [5] => Array ( [address] => 28, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [address1] => Andover Road [building] => 28 [county] => Gloucestershire [deliveryPointSuffix] => 1E [dependentLocality] => [dependentThorofare] => [doubleDependentLocality] => [flatNumber] => [houseName] => [houseNumber] => 28 [id] => |28||Andover Road||CHELTENHAM|Gloucestershire|GL50 2TJ|28|||1Ep|ElecM|NoGasM|NoIGT| [igtWarning] => Unknown [knownElectricityMeter] => 1 [knownGasMeter] => [name] => 28, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [postCode] => GL50 2TJ [town] => CHELTENHAM ) [6] => Array ( [address] => 30, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [address1] => Andover Road [building] => 30 [county] => Gloucestershire [deliveryPointSuffix] => 1F [dependentLocality] => [dependentThorofare] => [doubleDependentLocality] => [flatNumber] => [houseName] => [houseNumber] => 30 [id] => |30||Andover Road||CHELTENHAM|Gloucestershire|GL50 2TJ|30|||1Fq|ElecM|GasM|NoIGT| [igtWarning] => NoIGT [knownElectricityMeter] => 1 [knownGasMeter] => 1 [name] => 30, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [postCode] => GL50 2TJ [town] => CHELTENHAM ) [7] => Array ( [address] => 32, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [address1] => Andover Road [building] => 32 [county] => Gloucestershire [deliveryPointSuffix] => 1G [dependentLocality] => [dependentThorofare] => [doubleDependentLocality] => [flatNumber] => [houseName] => [houseNumber] => 32 [id] => |32||Andover Road||CHELTENHAM|Gloucestershire|GL50 2TJ|32|||1Gr|ElecM|GasM|NoIGT| [igtWarning] => NoIGT [knownElectricityMeter] => 1 [knownGasMeter] => 1 [name] => 32, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [postCode] => GL50 2TJ [town] => CHELTENHAM ) [8] => Array ( [address] => Phoenix Inn, 36, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [address1] => Andover Road [building] => 36 [county] => Gloucestershire [deliveryPointSuffix] => [dependentLocality] => [dependentThorofare] => [doubleDependentLocality] => [flatNumber] => Phoenix Inn [houseName] => [houseNumber] => 36 [id] => Phoenix Inn|36||Andover Road||CHELTENHAM|Gloucestershire|GL50 2TJ|36||||NoElecM|GasM|NoIGT| [igtWarning] => NoIGT [knownElectricityMeter] => [knownGasMeter] => 1 [name] => Phoenix Inn, 36, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [postCode] => GL50 2TJ [town] => CHELTENHAM ) [9] => Array ( [address] => 36, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [address1] => Andover Road [building] => 36 [county] => Gloucestershire [deliveryPointSuffix] => 1P [dependentLocality] => [dependentThorofare] => [doubleDependentLocality] => [flatNumber] => [houseName] => [houseNumber] => 36 [id] => |36||Andover Road||CHELTENHAM|Gloucestershire|GL50 2TJ|36|||1P0|ElecM|NoGasM|NoIGT| [igtWarning] => Unknown [knownElectricityMeter] => 1 [knownGasMeter] => [name] => 36, Andover Road, CHELTENHAM, Gloucestershire, GL50 2TJ [postCode] => GL50 2TJ [town] => CHELTENHAM ) ) )
```

Comment: Actually the value of variable are being overwritten. You have to create array to store all values or you can echo them in `foreach`

Comment: I have an array of results, I just updated the code, the problem is that it chooses the last result every time

Comment: you actually don't you just keep overwriting the values each time. You need to create an array and push the values into it at the end of each iteration, if you want to get all of them stored, instead of the last one. Briefly explaining, $flatnumber is i.e. = 1 first time round, but 10th time round it's = 10, and that's because the values are just assigned and not stored.

Comment: isn't my json_decode creating the array?

Comment: @scsitim Yes you can use array decoded by `json_decode`. Please post your Json array.

Comment: Added the json decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to over come this was to put all of the values into the option value, submit the form then explode the values once submitted.

```
        $result = $_POST['address1'];
        $result_explode = explode('|', $result);
        $flatnumber = $result_explode[0];
        $building = $result_explode[1];
        $street = $result_explode[2];


        <form method="post">
            <select name="address1">
        foreach($address as $addresses){
            echo '<option value="'.$addresses['flatNumber'].'|'.$addresses['building'].'|'.$addresses['address1'].'|'.$addresses['knownElectricityMeter'].'|'.$addresses['knownGasMeter'].'">'.$addresses['flatNumber'].' '.$addresses['building'].' '.$addresses['address1'].'</option>';  
        }
            </select>
        </form>
```